# Xdebug Installation not working. How to fix

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug, wampserver

I am trying to install Xdebug but its giving me a hard time.

1. I am running PHP 5.6.40. I downloaded the Xdebug `php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64`
2. I put it in the `ext` folder of my PHP folder.
3. I removed the zend_extension from the php.ini
4. I added the xdebugger in the XDebug tab.

Restarted the WAMP server but still not showing xdebug in the `phpinfo()`.

What am i doing wrong?

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/ext/php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11- nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:/wamp/tmp"
```

Comment: WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG already installed !>!>!>!>!>!>>!

Comment: And you need to use a Thread Safe dll and not the NTS (Not Thread Safe) dll

Comment: @RiggsFolly my answer wasn't that wrong then, hinting for the threading model. just don't understand why one would want to replace an extension, which is already there, as `phpinfo()` should have shown? the path to `zend_ext` does not matter too much, because they are not dynamically loaded into the server.

Comment: The reason why I replaced it was because I was following instructions in IntelliJ IDEA documentation which asked to replace it which caused the confusion. They should update their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of wamp you're using, but I run wamp 3.1.7 in which the php.ini file of apache comes already with the right xdebug extension. When you open apache/apache2.4.37/bin/php.ini and search for xdebug in the file, you find:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension="D:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.14/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="D:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

As you can see, xdebug extension is preinstalled in a zend_ext/ subfolder in your php folder. Xdebug is disabled by default, so you has to enable it by setting the right options to yes.